# Given three solutions of differential equation, to find its general solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

According to me answer is just linear combination of three given solutions but i donot know whether it is adequate , or i am missingsome trick.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not just any linear combination it should be $c_1y_1+c_2y_2+c_3y_3$ such that $c_1+c_2+c_3=1$. All solutions are of the form $a_1y_1+a_2y_2+y_p$ where $y_1,y_2$ are solutions of the homogeneous part and $y_p$ is the particular solution. So here when you take linear combinations the solutions of the homogenous part do not cause a problem but $(c_1+c_2+c_3)y_p$ should be $y_p$. that is why the second condition is required

Also if it is a second order linear differential equation then the solution space is of dimension $2$. So one of the solutions should be a linear combination of the other two. So linearly combining just two of them is sufficient.

Comment: @hapymath But why so

Comment: @godonichia edited my answer hope it answers your question

Comment: for a second order  homogeneous differential equation has atmost 2 solutions , but for non homogenous ode of 2nd order also have atmost 2 solutions ?

Comment: @godonichia yes to understand why say $y$ is a solution then $y-y_p$ solves the homogenous part so $y-y_p=c_1y_1+c_2y_2$

Comment: thank you i have undrstod second part of answer ,but i haven't got how got first condition ,

Comment: @godonichia for the first condition have you looked at the edited version of my answer? basically you have to put that condition so as to ensure that the coefficient of $y_p$ in the linear combination is 1 or else it will not be a solution

Answer (score 2):

A short way :

One observe that :  $y_2-y_1=x$ and $y_3+y_2-2y_1=xe^x$ which already gives two independant functions $x$ and $xe^x$. So the general solution is on the form $y=c_1x+c_2xe^x+f(x)$, where $f(x)$ doesn't contains an arbitrary constant. The three given solutions include the same term $-2x^2$. So $f(x)=-2x^2$ and the general solution is :
$$y=c_1x+c_2xe^x-2x^2$$

A longer way :

If you are not convinced, a systematic demonstration consists in bringing the three given solutions into the ODE :

$$-4+(1-4x)P(x)+x(1-2x)Q(x)=R(x)$$
$$-4+(2-4x)P(x)+2x(1-x)Q(x)=R(x)$$
$$\big(-4+(2+x)e^x\big)+\big(-4x+(1+x)e^x)\big)P(x)+x(e^x-2x)Q(x)=R(x)$$
Solve for $P$ , $Q$, $R$ the above system of three equations. This leads to :
$$P=-\frac{2+x}{x}$$
$$Q=\frac{2+x}{x^2}$$
$$R=2x$$
Then solve the ODE :
$$y''-\frac{2+x}{x}y'+\frac{2+x}{x^2}y=2x$$
The result is :
$$y=c_1x+c_2xe^x-2x^2$$

Comment: Hi thanks for answer .how did you solve for P, Q, R .and also in the end how did you concluded answerfrom given differential equation you made

Comment: Make linear combinations with the equations of the system in order to eliminate the unknowns one after the other up to get to the last one. This is the classical method of repeatitedly elimination of unknowns : 1.In the first equation, solve for one of the unknown in terms of the others.
2.Substitute this expression into the remaining equations. This yields a system of equations with one fewer equation and one fewer unknown.
3.Continue until you have reduced the system to a single equation.
4.Solve this equation, and then back-substitute until all the ubknowns are found

Comment: To solve the second order linear ODE, let $y(x)=x f(x)$ This yields to a very simple ODE and solve it.